# Py4JJavaError: An error occured while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext

Tags: python, sql-server, apache-spark, pyspark, odbc

I am trying to connect to a MSSQL database using pyodbc. I was able to get the connection working with pyodbc but when I try to initiate a PySpark session, I get a Py4JJavaError with the following message:

> An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.\n: org.apache.hadoop.security.KerberosAuthException: failure to login: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No LoginModule found for com.ibm.security.auth.module.

This is what my code looks like. I haven't been able to get past `spark = sqlContext.sparkSession` without the error. I want to create a spark session and then query a table into a spark dataframe.

```
appName = "PySpark SQL Server Example - via ODBC"
master = "local"
conf = SparkConf() \
    .setAppName(appName) \
    .setMaster(master) 
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
spark = sqlContext.sparkSession

server = 'exampleserver.windows.net'
database = 'exampledatabase'
username = 'exampleusername'
password = 'examplepassword'   
driver= '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'

conn = pyodbc.connect(f'DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER=tcp:'+server+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+';Trusted_Connection=yes')
query = f"SELECT TOP 3 ID, CountryId FROM dbo.Address"
pdf = pd.read_sql(query, conn)
sparkDF =  spark.createDataFrame(pdf)
sparkDF.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're getting seems like it could be related to, incorrect credentials or configuration on your machine. I would suggest double-checking that you have the correct username and password for the database. But I must suggest you before troubleshooting the PySpark issue, you should first check whether you can connect to the MSSQL database using pyodbc alone. To do this, try running the pd.read_sql command to fetch data from the database and verify that it works